# How to replace 0 value of input with predict value using the model in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, lstm

I have a dataset with three inputs.

X1, X2 and X3 are my inputs. I am trying to predict next value of X1 with previous inputs.

When I am predicting the next value of X1, some of previous input value of X1 is missing. Then predicted values will be shifted to that missing value and will be the input for next predicted value.

```
time     X1       X2       X3      predicted value of X1 (next)
 0       10       20       30          50
 60min   50       40       20          120
120min   120      20       80          240
180min   NaN      10       20          280
```

Here at 180 min My X1 input value is missing. So I want to put earlier predicted value `240`  replacing NaN

```
time         X1         X2      X3     predicted value
180 min  ** 240 **      10      20      280
```

I wrote the code, but It didn't work for me. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

```
pred=[]
for index, row in data.iterrows():
val = row['X1']
if np.isnan(val):
  f = row['X1','X2','X3']
  val = model.predict(f)
  pred.append(val)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly at the end of your code add one more line:

```
data.loc[index, 'X1'] = val
```

So your code will be:

```
    pred=[]
    for index, row in data.iterrows():
    val = row['X1']
    if np.isnan(val):
      data.iloc[index]['X1'] = pred[-1]
      row['X1'] = pred[-1]
    f = row['X1','X2','X3']
    val = model.predict(f)
    pred.append(val)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But still it is not working.

Comment: When I tried adding data.loc[index+1, 'X1'] = val still not working properly.

Comment: Yes, I fixed code again, i also don't know why do you need pred, it could be removed. And code don't work properly if in first raw X1 is nan. For prediction of nan when you find it, you should take previous raw.

Comment: Ya my code I guess I have to write after model predict. Actually what I want to say is if my X1 input is include with 0 value then take the previous pred value and then predict the next value

Comment: Thank you for the response , I will try that code also.

Comment: Finally I got the best code. Thank you very much for helping me.  If you are okay can you look at this problem, and can you give ma a suggestion for this?  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57196557/how-to-read-specific-column-with-specific-row-in-x-test-using-python"

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside data.iterrows(). As each column of DataFrame is a Series, you can access using the 'index' of data.iterrows() and assign using loc[]:

```
if np.isnan(val):
  data.loc[index, 'X1']= data['predicted value of X1 (next)'][index-1]
```

[Check documentation for more about loc and it's examples](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

Comment: when I used your code then measured values are displayed mostly 0 value.. Can you tell me this full code I have to apply before prediction or after model prediction.

Comment: after model prediction. The 'predicted value of X1 (next)' column needs to be filled first.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved using [pandas.DataFrame.fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna), below is a working example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[[float('nan'), 10, 20, 30],
         [1, 11, 21, 31]], 
    columns=['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'p_x1']
)
df.x1.fillna(df.p_x1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Can you little bit explain your code? I can't understand why you put p_x1

Comment: That's the column name for predicted values. I have created a simple data frame with four columns 'x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'p_x1', last line of code does the trick which will fill in the nan values in  column x1 from column p_x1.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

Comment: Hope it helps!!